# Any chance to get full autocompletion for Tensorflow 2.0 in PyCharm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, autocomplete, pycharm, tensorflow2.0

I have upgraded to tensorflow-gpu==2.0 and now I have very limited autocompletion in PyCharm (e.g. can't view a method signature). There seems to be some lazy loading mechanism that I'm not familiar with. Is there a way to have a full autocompletion working as in older TF versions?

Comment: Install PyCharm 2019.3 EAP https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/ It comes with a relevant fix for tensorflow completion. In the meantime PyCharm relies on some hardcoded data to provide the completion for tensorflow as it's too dynamic to be statically parsable. If you have any issues with the latest EAP - report them directly to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the answer here for the community even if the solution is present in the comment section.

Install `PyCharm` to latest version (2020.1 as of today) EAP [jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/)
It comes with a relevant fix for TensorFlow completion. In the meantime, `PyCharm` relies on some hardcoded data to provide the completion for TensorFlow as it's too dynamic to be statically parsable.
 If you have any issues with the latest EAP - report them directly to [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)